# Decoding OAuth2 JWT at API Gateway level vs at individual microservice level

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

I have developed a set of microservices (resource servers) using Spring Boot 1.5.x + OAuth2 with JWT. Right now each microservice is protected using Spring Security i.e. JWT access token is verified at individual resource server level. API Gateway does not have spring security in place, so it just routes the requests to appropriate  server and propagates the authentication headers to downstream services.

I wanted to know if there are any disadvantages of this setup compared to the one where AccessToken is verified at API gateway level only. Or is it just a matter of opinion? Doesn't keeping security at API Gateway level breaks principle of loose coupling, because each microservice may better understand the role of a given user in its own context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API management can do a small check on your JWT (fail early), BUT your microservices are the only one that can really manage all the security stuff !

If you set security only on api management it means that someone that can access your network will be able to push request to your API unauthenticated. 
You will not be able to log who do what. And finally, if you need to set some kind of ACL, it will not be possible (When you ask to list orders, you can only list YOUR order).

Perhaps you will think of decoding your JWT on the api management layers and push a header with user name to your backend to prevent all the thing I spoke about above, but I think it is not really a good practice.

First, access to network will means I'm able to be anybody. Then JWT is much more than just a username. For instance, perhaps you use scope on your authentication layers. ( scope read orders / scope modify orders / scope delete orders). This is useful to restrict what an application can do (either at client_id level) or what a user accept to give to the application ( scope share email ...). 
For this JWT on the backoffice is mandatory.

Ok you can do like username and extract data on api management and put specific headers to call backend, but really ? why do specific stuff ? oauth2 with JWT can do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is an interesting question. In our team we discussed about this topic a lot. Basically you have some parameters affecting the individual answer to this question. But you should always decode and verify granted tokens on the microservice level, too. Because they contain relevant information for authentication and in some cases even for authorization. If your microservices run in a enclosed environment (e.g. on enclosed Kubernetes cluster, where only the API-Gateway is available to the outside) you could use this "mixed" solution.

You can really consider just to verify the AccessToken at the API-Gateway and let the other microservices rely on the API Gateway. The API Gateway could than exchange the AccessToken into another AuthToken, only valid in the microservice-context. This new generated AuthToken can for example contain more sensitive application-bound information, because it is not exposed to the client. The Client gets only a so called opaque token. See https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/microservice-authentication-and-authorization-solutions-e0e5e74b248a
[image]